# assign macro to image in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have inserted an image with the following codes. Next, I want to select the newly inserted image immediately and assign a macro to picture and apply some formatting with it. I need your help.

```
        Sub InsertPicUsingShapeAddPictureFunction()
        Dim profile As String
        On Error GoTo 0
        Dim fd As FileDialog

        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        With fd
            .Filters.Clear
            .Filters.Add "Picture Files", "*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png"
            .ButtonName = "Select"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Title = "Choose Photo"
            .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
            .Show
        End With
        ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select

        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=fd.SelectedItems(1), _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
        Left:=ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Left + 2, _
        Top:=ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Top + 2, _
        Width:=123, _
        Height:=134

'here I am trying to select the inserted picture but the error is displayed

ActiveSheet.Shapes(fd.SelectedItems(1)).select

With selection
.onaction = "CustomMacro"
.placement = 1

End with


    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a Shape, it will be the last Shape on the sheet, so:

```
Sub InsertPicUsingShapeAddPictureFunction()
        Dim profile As String, sh As Shape
        On Error GoTo 0
        Dim fd As FileDialog

        Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
        With fd
            .Filters.Clear
            .Filters.Add "Picture Files", "*.bmp;*.jpg;*.gif;*.png"
            .ButtonName = "Select"
            .AllowMultiSelect = False
            .Title = "Choose Photo"
            .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
            .Show
        End With
        ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Select

        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture Filename:=fd.SelectedItems(1), _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
        Left:=ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Left + 2, _
        Top:=ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Top + 2, _
        Width:=123, _
        Height:=134

'here I am trying to select the inserted picture but the error is displayed


    Set sh = ActiveSheet.Shapes(ActiveSheet.Shapes.Count)
    With sh
        .OnAction = "CustomMacro"
        .Placement = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

*(Whenever I put a Shape on a sheet, I give it a `Name` so I can refer to it later)*

Comment: .select  at last,   Just awesome. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

If you assign a variable to the shape it is easy to reference it afterwards

```
Dim myShape as shape
set myShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture (Filename:=fd.SelectedItems(1), _
    LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
    SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
    Left:=ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Left + 2, _
    Top:=ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Top + 2, _
    Width:=123, _
    Height:=134)
```

You can then use the shape like this

```
myShape.TypeHereYourProperty ...
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but i am not able to use  "set myShape = "   i tried but codes are getting invalid with set myShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture (Filename:=fd.SelectedItems(1),_

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I find this strange - just tried it and works perfectly for me

        Dim myshape As Shape
        Set myshape = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddPicture(Filename:=fd.SelectedItems(1), _
        LinkToFile:=msoFalse, _
        SaveWithDocument:=msoCTrue, _
        Left:=ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Left + 2, _
        Top:=ActiveSheet.Range("B3").Top + 2, _
        Width:=123, _
        Height:=134)
        
        myshape.Height = 10 'or whatever other command you need

Comment: Maybe there were some syntax or next line issue with your earlier code. Now it seems to be ok. but I have uprated your answer. but I can't mark two answers as solved. thanks for your support.